# Show random questions from a table without repetition

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle

I am using moodle [Multitrack](https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_magtest) test for developing a career assessment test. I want to modify the plugin to show random questions, one question at a time. So if there are a total of 10 questions then it should show first a random question and after it is saved then show a random question from the remaining 9 questions and so on. Questions are saved in a table called 'magtest_question' whose fields are:

```
id(bigint),
magtestid(bigint),
questiontext(longtext),
questiontextformat(mediumint),
sortorder(bigint).
```

The questions are sorted based on the 'sortorder' column. So I tried changing the query to sort randomly.

```
SELECT * FROM {magtest_question} WHERE magtestid=? ORDER BY RAND()
```

But it will sometimes show the same question again. I want to avoid the questions which are attempted. How can I achieve this using sql query. Please help.

Comment: This won't show the same question again. This can be used to build an array of questions, arranged randomly. The same effect can be achieved by using (for instance) PHP's shuffle function.

Comment: +1 for Strawberries answer. Please check for duplicate values in your data table. The stated query shouldn't produce duplicate values.

Comment: @Djeramon      I tried with 5 questions, and it is showing the same question again.

Answer (score 1):

Query the ids of all 10 questions in a random order, store the ids in session in an array in the order returned by the query and then retrieve the questions one-by-one. This way you only issue an `order by rand()` query once and the questions will not be repeated.

Comment: There is paging. I want to show only one question at a time. So querying will be required.

Comment: This solution is the best approach. Make the RAND() in SQL to only retrieve the IDs in a session array. Then you read your array of question's IDs and for each of them you make a query to retrieve the information for that ID. That's how it should go and paging is not an issue

Comment: @ThomasG       Yes. It is ok for only one question at a time. The no. of questions in a page is a dynamic value. So at any time in future if I want to change the no. of questions in a page then it will be a problem.

Comment: @user1690835 no, it is not going to be a problem, since you store all ids in the session. You just query the number of questions using their ids from session indicated by your paging setting.

Comment: @Shadow        I didn't understand. Can you please share the code/query

Comment: @user1690835 it is the same query you used in your question.

Comment: @Shadow        The code for running sql is $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($magtest->id), $currentpage * $magtest->pagesize, $magtest->pagesize); So how I will do paging if query is run only for one time.

Comment: By storing the retrieved ids in session and retrieving and displaying question data for only those questions that are on a given page. So, paging is not done in the query, it is done on the data saved in the session as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the questions that have already been answered

Something like

```
$sql = "SELECT q.*
        FROM {magtest_question} q
        WHERE q.magtestid = :magtestid
        AND NOT EXIST (SELECT a.id
                       FROM {magtest_answer} a
                       WHERE a.questionid = q.id
                       AND a.userid = :userid)
        ORDER BY RAND()";

$params = array('magtestid' => $magtest->id, 'userid' => $USER->id);

$questions = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, $params, $currentpage * $magtest->pagesize, $magtest->pagesize);
```

Comment: How can I do paging here?